# Как можно исправить эту ошибку: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE

Tags: php, laravel

делаю todo-list на lavarel и хотел сделать изменение записи. Но у меня не получается и выходит эта ошибка:

```
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.
```

Пример кода:

```
 @foreach ($tasks as $task)
    <tr>
      
      <td>{{ $task->id}}</td>
      <td>{{ $task->name }}</td>
      <td>
      <a href="#">
      <i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i>
      </a>
      <form method="POST" action="{{ url('task/'.$task->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @csrf
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"> 
</form>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="bi bi-x-circle"> 
            </button>

</form>
      </a>
      <form action="{{ url('task/'.$task->id) }}" method="POST">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="bi bi-x-circle"> 
            </button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Покажите список роутов. И кстати `{{ csrf_field() }}` эквивалентно `@csrf`

Comment: что за странный код, и почему у Вас два закрывающихся тега формы при одном открытом??? `</form>`

Comment: Всем спасибо, что откликнулись!) @Simon, проблема действительно была в роутах.